# How to use split method in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, split

I have this code

```
    var array, key, dc;
    $.post("/mailchimp/check_mailchimp_key",
    {
      store_id: document.getElementsByName('data[store_id]')[0].value,
      mailchimp_api_key: document.getElementsByName('data[mailchimp_api_key]')[0].value,
      array: mailchimp_api_key.split('-'),
      key: array[0],
      dc: array[1]
    }
```

`store_id` and `mailchimp_api_key` work, but I have problem with others. This way it says `mailchimp_api_key is not defined` and my goal is to take whatever is stored in `mailchimp_api_key` and divide it to `key` and `dc`.

Comment: *mailchimp_api_key is not defined* … if it isn't defined then it doesn't have anything stored in it.

Comment: But it does. Since mailchimp_api_key on its own has whatever its written in input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> mailchimp_api_key: document.getElementsByName('data[mailchimp_api_key]')[0].value
> ```

… means that *when the object has finished being constructed* it will have a property called `mailchimp_api_key` with that value.

> ```
> mailchimp_api_key.split('-'),
> ```

… tries to read a **variable** called `mailchimp_api_key`.

There are two problems with this:

- A variable is not an object property
- The object property doesn't exist yet

---

Copy the value to a variable before you construct the object.

Use it twice.

```
var array, key, dc;

var mailchimp_api_key = document.getElementsByName('data[mailchimp_api_key]')[0].value;

$.post("/mailchimp/check_mailchimp_key",
{
  store_id: document.getElementsByName('data[store_id]')[0].value,
  mailchimp_api_key: mailchimp_api_key,
  array: mailchimp_api_key.split('-'),
  key: array[0],
  dc: array[1]
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you can't use it immediately in ajax call. Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ajax calls. It is just the basics of how object literals work.

Comment: I meant *objects

Answer (score 1):

This is not Javascript at all! You can't reference Object keys that you just defined.

```
var mailchimp_api_key  = document.getElementsByName('data[mailchimp_api_key]')[0].value;
var array = mailchimp_api_key.split('-');
var key = array[0];
var dc = array[1];
```

This way you get all the variables you need, then you might want to pass them in your Ajax call.